# Liferay portal: Builder service

Tags: java, liferay

I have used the builder service to create 2 tables: `Book` and `Author`.

A book has been written by many authors.

An author has written many books.

When I call the `BookLocalServiceUtil.del(bookId)` method of book (same for `Author`) to delete a `Book` entity, it doesn't seem to do anything. The `Book` entity still exists in the database.

Can anybody help me answer: why and how to fix this bug?

Comment: Please give us your 'service.xml' and 'BookLocalServiceImpl'.

Comment: can you provide us the code for `BookLocalServiceImpl`

Comment: 'service.xml' hasn't special. `BookLocalServiceImpl` is built by service SDK of liferay. I don't write override into it